# Unexpected end of file - new to bash_profile

Tags: bash, syntax, anaconda

be kind I am very new to coding. I have an unexpected end of file in by bash_profile and I can't debug it. Would someone with more experience mind taking a look and help me get to the bottom of it?

```
# pipx
export PATH="~/.local/bin:$PATH"

# pyenv
if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
  eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi

# poetry
export PATH="$HOME/.poetry/bin:$PATH"

# pip should only run if there is a virtualenv currently activated
export PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV=true

# commands to override pip restriction above.
# use `gpip` or `gpip3` to force installation of
# a package in the global python environment
# Never do this! It is just an escape hatch.
gpip(){
   PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV="" pip "$@"
}
gpip3(){
   PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV="" pip3 "$@"
}# added by Anaconda3 2019.07 installer
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda init <<<
```

Comment: `Unexpected end of file` - please post the full exact error message as it is at best including process name, file name and lien number. Is the file you posted your .bash_profile file? Where is it located? Is this your full bash_profile or you leaved something out? Is the error related to this file?

Comment: See `/usr/share/doc/bash/examples/`

Comment: Btw: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to replace `}#` with `} #` in line 24.

Comment: A newline or two might be even better than a space since it looks like that next chunk was appended to a file that didn't end with a new line.